# Finding duplicates using parameters

Tags: sql, t-sql

Whenever I look for duplicate values in a column, I write a little script like this:

```
SELECT COL1, COUNT(COL1)
FROM TABLE1 
GROUP BY COL1
HAVING COUNT(COL1) >1
```

It works, but I have to type.
So, I decided to try parameters:

```
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @column VARCHAR(100)

SET @table = 'TABLE1';
SET @column = 'COLUMN1';

SELECT @column, COUNT(@column)
FROM @table
GROUP BY @column
HAVING COUNT(@column) >1
```

SQL doesn't like this.  It states: *Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Line 34. Must declare the table variable "@table".*

If I slightly modify to use the table name:

```
DECLARE @column VARCHAR(100)
SET @column = 'COLUMN1';

SELECT @column, COUNT(@column)
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY @column
HAVING COUNT(@column) >1
```

I receive this error: *Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 51
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use a dynamic query to accomplish something like this.

```
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @column VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)

SET @table = 'TABLE1';
SET @column = 'COLUMN1';
SET @SQL = 
'SELECT ' + @column +' , COUNT( ' + @column + ')
 FROM ' + @table + '
GROUP BY ' + @column + '
HAVING COUNT(' + @column + ') >1'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thanks, great solution!